# How to say four-digit years without so many syllables

Tags: word-choice, modern-life

In English speech, we say the year 1992 not as "one thousand nine hundred ninety-two" but "nineteen ninety-two": five syllables rather than nine.

Has a convention like that evolved for Latin? (It's certainly had enough time!) "Mille nongenti nonaginta duo" is eleven syllables and *tempus pecunia est!*

Comment: Are you looking for modern Latin conventions? A Roman certainly would not have thought to make 1992 = 19 + 92, as it would have been written MCMXCII, with little room for redivision.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Yes, a modern convention—though any old precedents would be good to learn about in an answer. Interesting point about Roman numerals. Indeed I'm thinking of a world dominated by Arabic numerals, but Arabic numerals don't necessarily have to inspire the convention. Even counting years _ab urbe condita_ must have gotten to be a mouthful before Romulus Augustulus.

Comment: Does omitting part of the number count? (As in ninenty-two or _novecento_)

Comment: @Rafael Whatever the custom is, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: [Page of some interest](https://books.google.cl/books?id=aJuO3sbKOkEC&lpg=PA50&ots=rtQ4gLZ_SL&dq=vitae%20anno%20septuagesimo%20tertio&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=vitae%20anno%20septuagesimo%20tertio&f=false). Also the ancient custom of counting regnal years.

Comment: The book is from 1625 and gets to omit the century when it is clear enough: _ipso anno septuages[s]imo tertio_ (previously mentioned as _eius seculi_).

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I'm not sure if Roman numerals are a conclusive argument. They are certainly base-10 (I, X, C, M), but otherwise don't have much relation to the spoken language: XC -> *nonaginta*, XIX -> *undeviginti* (not *decem-un-de-decem*)

Comment: I agree with @brianpck. In French too you write "90" but you say quatre-vingt-dix.

Comment: @brianpck I didn't say it was a conclusive argument, but the premise is off. In English, 1992 is analyzed as 19 + 92 because of the way it was written, though that is compounded by shortening of hundred after 1900. So really it's nineteen [hundred] ninety-two, but because of the way it's written, that hundred is all but forgotten. The two work in tandem. You can test this by seeing phone numbers. 1-800-555-7324 (one, eight-hundred, five five five, seventy-three twenty-four).

Comment: @brianpck Re: Roman numbers v. spoken language, the point I'm making is that the visual word doesn't lend itself to reanalysis, which wouldn't necessarily impede a spoken reanalysis, but it wouldn't help it along either.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Thinking about it, I agree with your point. To take the phone number example: many European numbers are split into two digits and thus are "spoken" that way, even if they have the same amount of digits. I guess it's a separate, strange point how you could have a writing system that diverges so much from the spoken system: the Arabic system almost seems *necessary* to me, but that is probably cultural prejudice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a [15th century Medieval inscription](https://books.google.com/books?id=pRLMdAdJKAwC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138) that abbreviates to the last two numbers of the year (cf. "Summer of '69"):

> HIC IACET DOMINUS WILELMUS MEDELEY ABBAS HUIUS MONASTERII XII QUI OBIIT XII DIE MENSIS DECEMBRIS **ANNO** [DOMINI MILLESIMO QUADRINGENTESIMO] **SEPTUAGESIMO TERCIO** CUIUS ANIME PROPICIETUR DEUS AMEN.

Loose translation:

> Here lies the Sir William Medeley, the 12th abbot of this monastery, who died on the 12th day of the month of December in the **year '73**. May God look kindly on his soul.

Otherwise, I have been unable to find a consistent abbreviation.

This should not strike us as a gross omission. Obviously, the Romans never had to speak about years like this. English is actually fairly *unique* when it truncates a 4-digit year into 2 2-digit numbers. Consider 1999 (I'll exclude the word for "year"):

- **English:** nineteen ninety-nine (5 syllables!)
- **French:** mille neuf cent quatre-vingt-dix-neuf (8) or dix-neuf cent quatre-vingt-dix-neuf (8)
- [**German:**](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23325/how-to-read-years-in-german) neunzehnhundert[-]neunundneunzig (8) or neunzehnneunundneunzig (6--"more colloquial")
- **Spanish:** mil novecientos noventa y nueve (10 syllables with [Synalephas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha))
- **Italian:** millenovecento novantanove (11)
- **Latin:** [anno Domini] millesimo nongentesimo nonagesimo nono (16)

So sure, it's *longer*, but we're not talking about orders of magnitude.

As further evidence, both the [Vatican](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22anno+millesimo%22+site:vatican.va) and [*Nuntii Latini*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22anno+millesimo%22+site:http://ephemeris.alcuinus.net) have many examples of the full form without any attempt to shorten.

It is difficult to prove a negative (so I am happy to be contradicted!), but I think I can venture to claim that **there is no commonly occurring abbreviation of years in Latin.**

Comment: Are you sure the more-than-nine hundreds work in French and German? I thought it was an English-only feature...

Comment: You can check out the link for German. When I speak French I almost always use the first way, but I've been told (and [this site confirms](https://www.thoughtco.com/years-in-french-1368976)) that the second is also readily understood.

Comment: Wow! BTW in Spanish you can say _mil_ nueve _noventa y nueve_. It is NOT common to all the Spanish-speaking world, though, and it's informal, but it works.

Comment: How is English *unique* if you then show the exact same thing in your more colloquial German example ? Dutch behaves exactly like German, by the way.

Comment: @blage "fairly" unique, though based on Dutch perhaps it's more "unique" to Germanic languages.

Comment: Note that English uses cardinals and Latin uses ordinals for years. *Mille nongenti nonaginta novem* is shorter than *millesimus nongentesimus nonagesimus nonus*. In Finnish we fortunately use cardinals ("[vuonna] tuhat yhdeksänsataayhdeksänkymmentäyhdeksän") instead of ordinals ("tuhannentena yhdeksäntenäsadantenayhdeksäntenäkymmenentenäyhdeksäntenä vuonna" – very few will agree with me that this is easy to pronounce).

Comment: The year 1999 in Welsh is four syllables!  "Mil naw naw naw".